# Retrieving data from pivot table column in manytomany relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

users table has:

```
id   name   email
```

questions table has:

```
id   question
```

question_user (pivot table) has an extra field user_question_rating.

```
user_id   question_id   user_question_rating
```

User and Question has Many relations.

**User Model:**

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question');
}
```

**Question Model:**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

How do i find the user and question with given user_question_rating (e.g. 8)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withPivot()` function:

```
    public function users()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('user_question_rating');
    }
```

otherwise by default only relation keys will be returned